# jQuery UI datepicker: Configure keyboard shortcuts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I use the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) to let the user select a date. It has some shortcuts so that it can be controlled using the keyboard:

```
page up/down      - previous/next month
ctrl+page up/down - previous/next year
ctrl+home         - current month or open when closed
ctrl+left/right   - previous/next day
ctrl+up/down      - previous/next week
enter             - accept the selected date
ctrl+end          - close and erase the date
escape            - close the datepicker without selection
```

But it seems not user friendly for me. I did not find out myself how to select a date with the keyboard until I read it in the documentation. I guess only few users will find out that they have to press "CTRL + arrow keys" to select a date.

Therefore, I would like to replace the keyboard shortcuts with some other ones. Especially I would like that the user does not have to press the "Control" key when navigating with the arrow keys between days and weeks.

Because I did not find any configuration about this in the documentation, [I tried to achieve this aim using some custom javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/vH5SX/1/), where I listen for keyboard events and set the date manually. But it leads from one problem to another:

- It does only work fine after the first date was selected
- It interferes when the user uses "CTRL + arrow keys" after navigating with arrow keys only
- The date in the input field is immediately updated, unlike when navigating with "CTRL + arrow keys" of the datepicker's original keyboard control
- Other shortcuts of the browser do not work because of `event.preventDefault()`

I know that all of this problems can be solved by additional Javascript again, but I would prefer it if I could just configure this somehow.

Is it possible to configure the shortcuts of the jQuery UI datepicker?

Comment: FWIW I think your keyboard shortcuts are actually much more intuitive than the built in ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not configurable through datepicker.  You would have to change the `_doKeyDown` method  [source here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js#L524).

The easiest way to do this would be to extend the widget. It would look something like this:

```
$.extend($.datepicker, {
     _doKeyDown: function(event){
           //copy original source here with different
           //values and conditions in the switch statement
     }
});
```

Comment: Looks promising, but [I tried this](http://jsfiddle.net/vH5SX/2/) and it gives me an "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" (using Google Chrome). I am not familiar with the $.widget function, how do I call it correctly in this case?

Comment: Hey, sorry, I forgot that datepicker can't be extended through the widget factory... instead just use extend... updated http://jsfiddle.net/vH5SX/3/

Comment: @w4rumy your code is also working just fine see here: http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/stakv/ i just made minor changes and also i was looking for keyboard access to datepicker and you just made my mind on it.. Thank you!

Comment: @BerkerYüceer, nice one, thanks. My only suggestion would be adding `e.preventDefault()` at the start of the function to prevent the text cursor getting moved about the input field when the arrow keys are used. [Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stakv/41/).

Comment: Actually [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/stakv/42/) moves `e.preventDefault()` after the TAB key check so we can still tab out of the input field.

Comment: @Ambrosia Your fiddle was great help. One little issue, though. On selecting a date by `click`, it normally triggers a `CHANGE` event on the text input. Now, `Enter` key should reproduce this behaviour on keyboard navigation, shouldn't it?

Comment: how would you do navigation, when you have multiple months shown, not just one?

Comment: @Ambrosia Very nice code it solved my problem (wanted to detect del key in datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

you can check this add-on: 
http://hanshillen.github.io/jqtest/#goto_datepicker

for more accessibility options.

Comment: Link only answers are not good as they may go away and the answer is useless to others. Please include the relevant section as a quote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If its a `Jquery date picker` then by default it will support all of these shortcut. One issue might be there, i.e. `Theme`. You can use the `CSS CDN` given in `Jquery` Site itself. Then, focus will be visible even. Which is a great click for Accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace one of the shortcuts and do not like coping the code from the repository in case of updating the jquery ui library, use:

```
// original key down callback
var doKeyDown = $.datepicker._doKeyDown;
$.extend($.datepicker, {
    _doKeyDown: function(event){

        if(event.which !== $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
            doKeyDown(event);
        }
        else {
            //do something else
        }
    }
});
```

Keep a reference of **_doKeyDown** before you overwrite it and call it for all other shortcuts.