# Focus on jQuery UI Calender accessibility with TAB key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accessibility, jquery-ui-datepicker

We are using the jQuery [`datepicker`](//api.jqueryui.com/datepicker) to show calender control and provide an option to user to select a date from the keyboard without using mouse.

While testing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key accessibility for given form, I've noticed that when the focus reaches the date field, the calendar popup appears onscreen, but when I press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key again, the focus shifts to next input control but not to the calender popup.

Is there any way to shift the focus to the calendar control as soon as the popup is focused on?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="first input field">
<input type="text" id="myDate">
<input type="text" value="second input field">
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myDate").datepicker();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/Sb3Lh/1/)

**Code Fix**

After giving a try to various code fixes, ended up writing below code to enable accessibility for date picker.

```
$("#datepicker").attr('readonly', 'readonly')
            .datepicker({})
            .keydown(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                //   KEY MAP
                //  [TAB: 9, LEFT: 37, UP: 38, RIGHT: 39, DOWN: 40]
                var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
                // If key is not TAB
                if (code != '9') {
                    // And arrow keys used "for performance on other keys"
                    if (code == '37' || code == '38' || code == '39' || code == '40') {
                        // Get current date
                        var parts = $(this).val().split("/"),
                            currentDate = new Date(parts[2], parts[0] - 1, parts[1]);
                        // Show next/previous day/week 
                        switch (code) {
                            // LEFT, -1 day
                            case 37:
                                currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 1);
                                break;
                                // UP, -1 week
                            case 38:
                                currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 7);
                                if (!_.isNull(currentDate)) {
                                    $(this).datepicker("setDate", currentDate);
                                    return false;
                                }

                                break;
                                // RIGHT, +1 day
                            case 39:
                                currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
                                break;
                                // DOWN, +1 week
                            case 40:
                                currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 7);
                                break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    } // If other keys pressed.. return false
                }
            });
```

Comment: Are you wanting to tab through the fields and dates on the calendar itself then go to your next field?

Comment: @Jason yes, i want to tab through all the dates

Comment: Did you end up finding an appropriate solution for your issue? If so, could you share?

Comment: @ScottMcConnell post is updated with the code fix which i ended up writing to support accessibility on datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the datepicker fields/controls can be tabbed thru.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ shows that the datepicker has specific keyboard interactions built in, perhaps because they realized tab was not a viable option.  This post, [jQuery UI datepicker: Configure keyboard shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459562/jquery-ui-datepicker-configure-keyboard-shortcuts), talks about changing them which might help you out.

Comment: this information is really helpful. Thanks for providing me the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The year is 2021 and sadly I had the same issue. Was really disappointed when I saw there was no published fix for this issue, so after a couple of days of work, I managed to find a workaround. Screen readers make life harder for everyone and sometimes they can't even read that you press a key (in my case with NVDA on the browser was not reading any of the arrow keys, even if I tried using them in combination with CTRL/CMD). The biggest problem is that the html block is being created at the end of the body, so you have to force focus into that block. See below how I managed to make the JQuery UI Datepicker accessible on desktop and mobile:

```js
function setVoiceOverFocus(element) {
  var focusInterval = 10; // ms, time between function calls
  var focusTotalRepetitions = 10; // number of repetitions

  element.attr('tabindex', '0');
  element.blur();

  var focusRepetitions = 0;
  var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    element.focus();
    focusRepetitions++;
    if (focusRepetitions >= focusTotalRepetitions) {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, focusInterval);
}
if (window.util.isMobile()) {
  $(".Form__CustomInput").on("click", function () {
      $(this).attr("selected-input", "true");
      setVoiceOverFocus($(".ui-state-default:first"));
      $(".ui-datepicker").attr("role", "dialog");
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").attr("tabindex", "-1");
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar thead").attr("aria-hidden", "true");
  });

  $(document).on("click", function () {
      $(".ui-state-default").on("click", function () {
          setVoiceOverFocus($("[selected-input = 'true'"));
          $("[selected-input = 'true'").attr("selected-input", "false");
          $(".ui-datepicker").hide();
          $(".ui-datepicker").attr("display", "none");
      });

      $(".ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next").on("click", function () {
          setVoiceOverFocus($(".ui-state-default:first"))
          $(".ui-datepicker").attr("role", "dialog");
          $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").attr("tabindex", "-1");
          $(".ui-datepicker-calendar thead").attr("aria-hidden", "true");
      });
  })
  } else {
  //open form with arrow up/down
  $(".Form__CustomInput").on("keydown", function (event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 40 || event.keyCode === 38) {
          $(this).attr("selected-input", "true");
          setVoiceOverFocus($(".ui-state-default:first"));
          $(".ui-datepicker").attr("role", "dialog");
      }
  });
  //when you select the date close the calendar and focus the input
  $(".Form__CustomInput").on("change", function () {
      setVoiceOverFocus($("[selected-input = 'true'"));
      $("[selected-input = 'true'").attr("selected-input", "false");
      $(".ui-datepicker").hide();
  });

  $(document).on("keydown click", function (event) {
      var uiDatePicker = ".ui-datepicker";
      var calendarDay = ".ui-state-default";
      var calendarArrows = ".ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next";
      var selectedInputElement = "[selected-input = 'true'";
      var selectedInputAttr = "selected-input";
      var isFocus = ":focus";

      function exitDatePicker () {
          setVoiceOverFocus($(selectedInputElement));
          $(selectedInputElement).attr(selectedInputAttr, "false");
          $(uiDatePicker).hide();
      };

      if ($(calendarDay).is(isFocus) && event.keyCode === 27) {
          exitDatePicker();
      };
      if ($(".TimePicker").length) {
          if ($(uiDatePicker + "-period:last").is(isFocus) && event.keyCode === 9) {
              event.preventDefault();
              exitDatePicker();
          }
      } else {
          if ($(calendarDay + ":last").is(isFocus) && event.keyCode === 9) {
              event.preventDefault();
              exitDatePicker();
          }
      }
      if ($(calendarDay + ":first").is(isFocus) && event.keyCode === 9 && event.shiftKey) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $(uiDatePicker + "-header " + calendarArrow).attr("tabindex", "0");
          setVoiceOverFocus($(uiDatePicker + "-next"));
      };
      if ($(uiDatePicker + "-prev").is(isFocus) && event.keyCode === 9 && event.shiftKey) {
          event.preventDefault();
          exitDatePicker();
      };

      $(calendarDay).on("click", function () {
          setVoiceOverFocus($(selectedInputElement));
          $(selectedInputElement).attr(selectedInputAttr, "false");
          $(uiDatePicker).hide();
      });

      $(calendarArrows).on("click", function () {
          setVoiceOverFocus($(calendarDay + ":first"));
          $(uiDatePicker).attr("role", "dialog");
      });
  });
}
```