# jQuery Datepicker: select month with tab key

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker, keydown

I'm stuck trying to enable a keydown event on the "Next Month" button in jQuery datepicker.

The idea is to let users select the date without using a mouse, only tabulation and Enter key.

I know that there is a keydown map for the datepicker (http://hanshillen.github.io/jqtest/#goto_datepicker), but I want something easier and intuitively understandable. By the way, there's no "page down" button on my Mac (which is reserved for "next month"), so I cannot navigate through the datepicker using this default key settings.

By default, on tabulation "previous month" and "next month" buttons don't even come into focus. Still, I can solve this by adding "tabindex" attribute to the corresponding div. But even in the focus, the button doesn't respond to Enter key. Only clicking works.

Here's html of this piece of datepicker:

```
<a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all ui-state-hover 
ui-datepicker-next-hover ui-state-active" data-handler="next" 
data-event="click" title="Next" tabindex="1"><span class="ui-icon 
ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Next</span></a>
```

(I added classes `"ui-state-hover ui-datepicker-next-hover ui-state-active"` using my javascript function).

What's next? Is this is the issue of changing `data-event="click"` to something else? I tried to do it, as well as to find the corresponding functions or handlers in both jquery.js and jquery-ui.js files, but failed. I've really got poor knowledge of advanced javascript and jQuery UI, as there must be some simple solution for this problem.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

P.S. Here, in StackOverflow I read lot's of discussions, but only this one:  [Focus on jQuery UI Calender accessibility with TAB key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714217/focus-on-jquery-ui-calender-accessibility-with-tab-key) seems to deal with datepicker accessibility / tabulation issue and still nothing is said there about selecting months.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution based on the fact that the anchor tags for next/prev month are missing a href attribute, reason for which they do not receive focus (at least in chrome):

```
$('.js-calendar').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        altField: '.js-date-input',
        onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                // add href to prev/next anchors so that they can receive TAB focus
                $('.ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next').attr("href", "#");
            }, 50);
        }
    });

// add href to prev/next anchors so that they can receive TAB focus
$('.ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next').attr("href", "#");
```

Notice I added the hrefs outside the datepicker call (for initial purposes) and also in the onChangeMonthYear function (otherwise, they are lost after a change of month).

Note: using jquery-ui-1.11.2

Comment: Thank you! Good point! I've solved the problem with next/prev month buttons not receiving focus by adding a `tabindex` attribute to them: `$(".ui-datepicker-next").attr("tabindex", "2");`. As for lose of attributes (and seemingly event handlers), I wrote a custom function with a recursive call because I could not figure out how to use of jQuery DP API for this purpose. Now I tried to adapt your solution (great!) and it partially works. Still, cannot understand why it is needed to `set timeout`? Why otherwise the function inside `onChangeMonthYear()` isn't called at all?

Comment: The setTimeout is a hack to the problem that when onChangeMonthYear event triggers, the new calendar table is not yet created.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to post here a solution I've finally come up with. I'm not totally happy with it, by still this code does what I wanted, i.e.:

1. 'next month' button comes into focus when Tab key is hit
2. on Enter key, user can move to the next month
3. if this is the desired month, then pressing Tab moves focus to month days (one can access the needed day by successively hitting Tab)
4. if this is NOT the desired month, then on Enter key user skips to the next month and steps 3–4 are repeated.

The major problem was that after selecting next month, the 'next' button on datepicker went out of focus and even when I managed it, the button didn't respond to Enter key. This is probably because the button is accessed by class name and after the month is changed in the datepicker, the element this class is referred to changes also (it's not, say, link to September, but to October instead). So, trying to trigger keydown (Enter) event for the second (or third, fourth etc) time on **the same** element didn't work. I guess this is also why I wasn't able to use `this` instead of `className` inside jQuery selectors.

I solved this by triggering keydown event inside separate function that **calls itself**.

Here's the code (which also includes some basic styling for the button depending on whether it is in focus or not):

```
function out_of_focus(id) {
    $(id).blur(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("ui-state-active");
    });
 }

 $(".ui-datepicker-next").attr("tabindex", "1");
 $(".ui-datepicker-next").focus(function() {
    tabulation();
 });

function tabulation() {
    $(".ui-datepicker-next").addClass("ui-state-active");
    $(".ui-datepicker-next").keydown(function(evt) {
      if (evt.which == 13) {
        $.datepicker._adjustDate("#datepicker", +1, "M");
        $(".ui-datepicker-next").attr("tabindex", "2");
        $(".ui-datepicker-next").focus();
        tabulation();
        out_of_focus(".ui-datepicker-next");
      }
  });
}
out_of_focus(".ui-datepicker-next");
```

Any suggestions on how to improve this are appreciated.